# Highcharts: Marker radius does not seem to work

Tags: highcharts

I am having trouble getting the marker radius working with high stock charts.  I have been trying to get this working using both plot options, and a setting against the series directly:

`plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        marker: {
                            radius: 90
                        }
                    }
                },`

(or see http://jsfiddle.net/zMH7Q/).

Changing other attributes such as the marker shape works fine, but any changes to the radius seem to be ignored.  I have tried setting this in both plot options, and directly against the series but to no avail.  It is definately mentioned in the documents (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.area.marker.radius) so should work unless I am doing something stupid (fairly likely).

Any help would be appreciated :-)

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HighStock, unlike HighCharts, the default for marker is enabled: false, this is because the data tends to be very dense and markers wouldn't add much value to the data comprehension of the user.

You need to modify your code to:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            radius: 90
        }
    }
},
```

for the markers to show up.

**EDIT:** I will leave the above up in case someone comes across this and needs it.  What David really wants to know is whether the series symbol during hover can be changed.  The code for that is:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    lineColor: null,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            fillColor: 'white',
                            radius: 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Which is straight from the Highcharts API reference at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.marker.states.hover.radius

Comment: It is entirely possible I miss-worded the question of used the wrong term.  It is the "marker" that appears under the mouse cursor in the example that I would like to change the radius of - I do not want markers permanently appearing on the chart...  Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: @DavidHiblen changed my answer to fit your comment

Comment: I tried the solution above but with radius 0 to actually make the on-hover markers invisible, didn't work. Do you know how to make those markers completely invisible?

Comment: I've found out that values near 0 make the markers almost invisible (0 doesn't work as expected):
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: false,
                marker: {
                  enabled: true,
                  radius: 0.01,
                  fillColor: 'white',
                    states: {
                      hover: {
                        radius: 0.01
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        },